# Using Web.Release.Config transforms in Code First Migrations (MVC 5)

Tags: azure, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to setup code first migrations for an MVC 5 web application hosted in Azure. The problem I am running into is that the migrations only take place on the LocalDB and not the database hosted on Azure.

Currently I have the following setup. I have the connection string for the local DB in my Web.Conf file as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="InterestedPersonDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\InterestedPerson.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then in my Web.Release.config I have transforms setup as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="InterestedPersonDBContext"
     connectionString="Server=tcp:u756l4y29q.database.windows.net,1433;Database=SkillsMatrixDB;User ID=MyID;Password=MyPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

This setup works fine for running the application on both the LocalDB and the Azure hosted DB, however code first migrations only affect the local DB. Is there a way (other than changing the connection string in the Web.Config file) to have code first migrations also apply to the Azure DB?

Comment: The connection string is only changed when you publish the site. Si when you are in visual studio, and you add a migration, you only target the one database in your connection string. In your case your local DB.

Comment: @BjornVdkerckhove so is there any way to have to migrations act on both databases?

Comment: No, That is the reason we don't use a local DB, but start with the azure DB. If you want to use both, put a second connection string in the web.config, put it in comment and everuthing you create a migration you need to use update-database for both connection strings.

Comment: @BjornVdkerckhove Thanks, that's basically what I've done, I was just hoping there was another way.